# zip giving error in updating code from python 2.7 to python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-zip

I am trying to update some code written in python 2.7 for use in python 3.9. A line using the 'zip' function keeps throwing an error.

```
mask_1 = np.asarray([w1 & w2 for w1,w2 in zip(mask_1[::2],mask_1[1::2])])
```

The error reads:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

My understanding is that I should cast 'zip' into the form of list for python 3.9 i.e.:

```
mask_1 = np.asarray([w1 & w2 for w1,w2 in list(zip(mask_1[::2],mask_1[1::2]))])
```

Then the error becomes

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

It would appear that '&' is an acceptable operand for 'str' types in python 2.7 but not python 3.6. What is a suitable workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the thing that `for` operates doesn't have to be a `list`, so that's why changing that changes anything.

The problem is exactly as stated in the error: you're trying to use the binary operator `&` on strings (type `str`), and that makes no sense. So, that's a bug somewhere else!

Probably, you have some logic somewhere that assumes that strings are essentially bytes; that's not true under Python3. So, find the code that creates `mask_1` and make sure it actually creates something that contains integers that can be combined using `&` – either something like an actual `bytes` object, or any container of integers; be it just a list of ints, or a numpy ndarray of uint8, or something else.